# npm not reading .npmrc file

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm trying to install a library from a private repository, and I keep getting an error in trying to use npm.

I'm using:
OSX Mavericks 10.9.3
Node v0.10.28
npm 1.4.10 (this was installed after trying with 1.4.13 and it still not working)

I am running this from my home directory, and the `~/.npmrc` file is in the directory.

whenever I run the command: `npm install 'library name here'`

I get the following error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dslib-js
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/dslib-js
npm ERR! 404 404 Not Found: dslib-js
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'dslib-js' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Maybe try 'npm search dslib'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "dslib-js"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/marcos.pedreiro
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.10
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/marcos.pedreiro/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Edits:

When I run `ls -a` (in the home directory) this is the output:

```
.           .ssh            Music
..          .subversion     Pictures
.CFUserTextEncoding .vagrant.d      Public
.DS_Store       Applications        VirtualBox VMs
.Trash          Desktop         clients
.bash_history       Documents       dev
.gradle         Downloads       npm-debug.log
.matlab         Google Drive        ~:.npmrc
.npm            Library         ~:.npmrc.template
.npmrc.bak      Movies
```

This is the output of the command `npm config ls -l | grep config`

```
; cli configs
globalconfig = "/usr/local/etc/npmrc"
userconfig = "/Users/marcos.pedreiro/.npmrc"
```

:End Edits

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If what you posted is truly the output of `ls -a`, then the filename is wrong.

`~:.npmrc` should be named `.npmrc`.

The ~ at the beginning suggests you used a shell shortcut to place the file in your home directory (maybe something like `cp .npmrc ~:.npmrc`.  The trouble is likely the colon.  `~/` will be interpreted as "my home directory", but `~something/` will be interpreted as the home directory of the user named `something`.  Since there is no user `something`, the system is probably just treated ~: as literal text.

Try renaming the file and see if that works:

```
mv "~:.npmrc" .npmrc
```

Answer (score 31):

In my case the character encoding was wrong for some reason, I had to convert it to UTF-8.

I used "npm get" to discover the problem, the result was full of u/2411... strings.

Comment: This happened to me.  I created my `.npmrc` file from Powershell with the `New-Item` command, and the encoding was `UCS-2 LE BOM` instead of `UTF-8`.

Comment: Good call out, I had to open the file in Notepad++ and change the encoding. Fixed the issue.

Comment: This solved it for me. In my case I didn't see any weird characters. I opened my .npmrc file with Visual Code, and down in the corner I could see that the file was UTF-16 for some reason. I just saved it as UTF-8 and it worked.

Comment: Wow! Been dealing with tracking down the same problem and this resolved for me. Thanks! Feel this should be something called out in their docs more.

Comment: In my case, even though `npm get` was showing proper output, after opening in VSCode, I realized that the real file name is `.npmrc.rtf`. I created a new `.npmrc` using VSCode and it fixed my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76161802/7801965

Answer (score 8):

For people running Windows, check if Windows is hiding file extensions. For me, Windows was saying that the file name was `.npmrc`, but the real file name was `.npmrc.txt`.

Removing the `.txt` extension fixed the issue.

Comment: This happened to me. Even though I had originally created the file as .npmrc, notepad added the .txt back when I saved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, For me the name was ".npmrc.npmrc". You can rename the file on Windows in Powershell with "$ mv .npmrc.txt .npmrc"

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming the Node package `dslib-js` is contained within your private npm repository.  You'll need to set that repository in your local `.npmrc` file.  For example, if your repository was at `http://myrepo.com:4000` you would run the following command:

```
$ npm set registry "http://myrepo.com:4000"
```

The error your getting above is because the package `dslib-js` is not available on the npmjs.org, as you can see from visiting this URL: https://www.npmjs.org/package/dslib-js.  By default (without a registry set in your `.npmrc` file), npm will search `https://registry.npmjs.org` (which can be browsed on the web via the URL I pasted above).

Comment: Perhaps that is why the OP has a .npmrc file and is seeking advice on why that file is ignored?

Comment: It's possible it's being ignored, but the output shows `npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dslib-js` which leads me to believe the file exists, but doesn't have a registry set.  If the OP could paste the output of the `.npmrc` file that would help answer this :)

Comment: @Brandon good catch, I missed the misspelling of the `.npmrc` file :)

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps anyone landing here: I had a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file in the project root that was overriding the `registry` config from `.npmrc`. Removing the shrinkwrap file solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I missed a couple of things to download my packages published in my private repository.

**First** The file name was `.npmrc.txt` instead of `.npmrc`. In windows, you can't create file name directly. So I opened command prompt then fired

```
echo "auth_token" > .npmrc
```

**Second** I was just pasting my `auth_token` in `.npmrc` file. You have to append the registry address also.

```
//**.**.visualstudio.com/_packaging/**/npm/registry/:_authToken=token_here
```

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone... my issue was I created the .npmrc file in a text editor so npm was ignoring the file because of the permissions on it. In order to fix it I deleted the file. Then I remade the file through the command line.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure it was ignored because of the permissions, or because it had the wrong file extension?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone has the same issue as me. We have a private registry but before adding the .npmrc file I tried running `npm install`. This created the package-lock.json and it was overriding the new registry that was added in the .npmrc file.

Simply deleting the package-lock.json and re-running `npm install` fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case (MacOS), in Finder app, it was showing up as `.npmrc` in `/Users/<User-Name>` but when I opened the file in `VSCode` instead of `TextEdit`, the real filename turned out to be `.npmrc.rtf` with bunch of garbage characters inside.

I created a new `.npmrc` using VSCode and it started working!

Once it is fixed `npm get` command will show up the path of `.npmrc` file in the output.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a scenario where `npm ci` was not picking/reading configs from .npmrc file.

Replacing it with `npm install` resolved the issue.

Node version 10.18.0

Comment: This is what happened for me when I deployed a Google Cloud Function with a private repo and `.npmrc` included to source code archive created by `gcloud functions deploy` - its build step uses `npm ci` instead of `npm install`. Now I have to research how (if possible) to enforce this build script to to use `npm install` command instead of `npm ci` during function deployment...

Comment: A follow up. My problem with `npm ci` and `.npmrc` as part of deploying a Google Cloud functions was caused by broken handwitten `.npmrc' syntax and npm was not so informative in messages. There was is a syntax error in the handwritten `.npmrc`. My syntax errors were 1) instead of `@scope:registry=https://registry.example.com` it was `@scope=https://registry.example.com` and 2) instead of `//registry.example.com:_authToken=TOKEN_LITERAL` it was `registry.example.com:authToken=TOKEN_LITERAL`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different reason of npm not picking up the .npmrc. But after *changing* the registry setting in my project's .npmrc file I had to delete previously existing node_modules folder and package-lock.json, then install with `npm install --save`. Doesn't make much sense, but after this, the package-lock.json file (re)created was using the correct registry.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem mentioned in the question, I have resolved the problme in the following way

**step 1:** I went to the user directory in the c drive
C:\Users\user1

**step 2:** Found text.npmrc file which in the text format

**step 3:** I just replaced the file text.npmrc to .npmrc

**step 4:** after run npm install it working fine as i expected

Answer (score 0):

Supported options in the `.npmrc` file format have changed over time, so if your `.npmrc` seems to be ignored, you may accidentally be running against an old version of the npm cli. Perhaps you have a new machine, a busted `$PATH`, a docker image with an old nodejs version, some LTS linux distribution with an ancient nodejs, etc.

In my case, `.npmrc` looked like

```
registry = https://repo.corp/npm
always-auth = true

# Note: `//` IS NOT A COMMENT in this file! `#` and `;` are the comment chars
#
# See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc#comments
# and https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc#auth-related-configuration
#
# Also note that the trailing / on the URL is required
//repo.corp/npm/:_authToken=${CORP_NPM_REPO_TOKEN}
```

and this works just fine with the npm 7+ cli. Node 16 comes with npm 8, so that works fine too.

But if by accident I use node 14, which comes with npm 6 by default, or something even older than that, I get `E401 npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Corp Realm"` which makes it seem that the `.npmrc` isn’t being read, or the token in `$CORP_NPM_REPO_TOKEN` has expired, when it’s really just a problem with the npm cli version being too old.